# .htaccess treating $_GET= as variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I understand .htaccess and ?var=$1, what I'm trying to do is treat $1 as a standalone, such as

```
http://localhost.com/file.php?stackoverflow
```

Would be equivalent to

```
http://localhost.com/file.php?site=stackoverflow
```

I'm guessing this has to be done in the same way the way I stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the site always should be the first querystring parameter:

```
$site = "";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$_){
  $site = $key;
  break; //breaks at first run, as site should be the first querystring parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can** use this method although I'd recommend using a conventional method that you listed below...

For a URL of `http://localhost.com/file.php?stackoverflow`, if you wanted to test the existence of that parameter, you'd be able to use something like this -

```
if (isset($_GET['stackoverflow']){
  // parameter exists.
}
```